# how to open file explorer, network directory from php

Tags: php, file

Hello my client wants to be able to add a link to a file directory in network

How can I invoke opening this via php. I know that browsers can't handle url like `file://c:/`

this just won't work (i've tested) so how can I open directory like this or like `\\db-mssql\iopro2012`

Comment: Sorry, when you are talking about a webbrowser and a server side application in php which is meant to offer this feature: that is technically impossible and for a very good reason: it would be a massive security thread since it would mean that the server would get access to the clients file system.

Comment: Oh, and btw: this has _nothing_ to do with php. It is irrelevant _how_ you create the page you load in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about opening a network share from the server, [try this](http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/34-web/66-accessing-smb-servers-with-php)

If you want the client to open a network share upon clicking a link or something similar, this isnt going to be possible with browsers default settings. It is possible to change the settings to allow this in some browsers, [see here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_%3a_Issues_%3a_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work)

But basically, you are trying to do something that shouldn't be done.

Answer (score -1):

server side PHP can't open file explorer;
But,Using some hack tech can do it;You need some others program language building a listener....Now, you know what i mean.

Comment: This is quite an old question you are answering, it's likely that the asker has moved on since. If you are going to provide an answer, please be more specific about a solution rather than referring to some "hack tech" - it is too obscure to be of use.

Comment: All right,I can give a way,You can use Python's watchdog package or c# FileSystemWatcher make an listener,When php command(like file_put_content()) change a file's content then trigger the listener run the system command like open file explorer.(Do you feeling it like a Trojan horse？）